# How to detect if Enter was pressed in txtMessage_TextChanged() ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to find out if Enter was pressed in

```
private void txtMessage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 // do something

}
```

But I can't do this :

```
private void txtMessage_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
   {
   // Then Enter key was pressed
   }              
}
```

Since `txtMessage_TextChanged` doesn't have this overload .

Any suggestions ? thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to an event that actually captures that information.

The `KeyPress` event fires before `TextChanged`, so you could use a `bool` to indicate whether the `Enter` key was pressed.

```
bool enterKeyPressed = false;

private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    enterKeyPressed = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter);
}

private void txtMessage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (enterKeyPressed)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

register to this:

`this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.Login_KeyPress);`

In that method set a boolean or something if keychar == 13

Answer (score 0):

you can use keypress event to capture enter key event